Is it enough to meet statutory minimum leave entitlement "on average"?
I'm trying to understand the statutory minimum leave entitlement in the UK (and England & Wales specifically). I believe the entitlement arises from regulations 13 and 13A of The Working Time Regulations 1998 and amounts to 5.6 weeks' leave in total, subject to a maximum of 28 days.
The government issues guidance on how holiday entitlement is calculated and also a calculator which, depending on a worker's schedule, gives a leave entitlement expressed in either days, shifts or working hours. I understand from using the calculator that these values are arrived at using averages (e.g. the average number of working hours per week, or per day, or the average no of shifts per week, etc.). Careful use of those averages allows conversion of the entitlement between units of weeks, days, shifts and hours. This works, on average.
My question concerns an employer that requires workers to take leave in larger units than those suggested by the government's calculator. This also works on average, but depending on how the leave is taken in any particular year, may fall below the entitlement given in the smaller units. This is getting a little abstract, so, for a concrete example, let's say:

Workers are scheduled to work 10 shifts in a pattern of 14 days. The pattern alternates between a 4-shift week and a 6-shift week. This is an average of 5 shifts per week. The government calculator says each worker is entitled to 28 shifts of leave.
The employer gives each worker 8 shifts to be booked-off individually, and then 4 blocks of length one week. On average, each block is equivalent to 5 shifts, so 4 blocks makes 20 shifts, plus the 8 individual shifts makes 28 shifts, and the employer claims they meet the minimum.
However, in a particular year, a worker might take all 4 blocks on 4-shift weeks. After booking all of their leave, they realise that they only received 16 shifts off during their blocks, making a total for the year of only 24 shifts.

If the worker asks for an additional 4 shifts of leave, should they receive it? And if the employer refused, would we expect a tribunal to find for the employer or the worker?
Added: Discussions in comments have helped me clarify that I'd like to understand, if the employer is indeed wrong to refuse the "extra" 4 shifts of leave, how best to argue that case. I agree with several commentors that expressing the entitlement in hours and only deducting hours scheduled during a period of leave from it is the most reasonable method, but I struggle to explain why in the face of "you've had 4 weeks, plus 8 days (worth 1.6 weeks), and so you've had all of your entitlement". There does seem to be a gap of interpretation between the 5.6 weeks in the regulations and the figures from (mere) guidance, so how can I show that my interpretation is better than theirs?

In your example, couldn't the worker also take all 4 blocks in 6-shift weeks and then receive 32 shfits off in total?

Yes, exactly. I wonder if that gives the employer any wiggle room i.e. can they use the argument that the worker had the opportunity to take the full entitlement, but chose not to, so there's no detriment (if that's the right word)? And if that were the case, presumably it would it be different if the employer mandated that all block leave was taken in 4-shift weeks?

I added clarification that I'd like to see reasoning for prefering one interpretation over others. Please advise if this is too large a change to the intent of my question, and if I should instead ask another.

Note that getting only 28 days of holidays in the UK is rare. Many people get more than 20 days of holidays plus 8 bank holidays. If you got 23 days + 8 days bank holidays per your contract, then a low stating that you must be given 28 days of holidays doesn't protect you if you think you are cheated out of 1-3 of your 31 days.

The worker is not entitled to a number of shifts, as such. They are entitled to the equivalent of 5.6 weeks pro rata (and subject to conditions, etc etc).
Alice works a 7.5 hour day, 5 days a week. She's entitled to (5 x 5.6) 28 of these days or (7.5 x 5 x 5.6) 210 hours of paid leave.
Bob works a 7.5 hour shift, 5 days a week. He's entitled to (5 x 5.6) 28 of these shifts or (7.5 x 5 x 5.6) 210 hours of paid leave.
It's the same entitlement, whether we call the work period a 'day' or a 'shift'.
In your scenario your worker happens to work an alternating pattern of shifts.

The pattern alternates between a 4-shift week and a 6-shift week. This is an average of 5 shifts per week.

An ordinary 5 days a week worker works an average of 5 days a week.

Following some questions in comments, look at this another way:
The scenario's hypothetical worker Charlie has shifts 7.5 hours long and they work an average of 5 shifts a week. This is equivalent to ordinary full-time employee Alice who works 7.5 hours a day, five days a week.
Charlie and Alice work the same hours so they are entitled to the same amount of statutory minimum leave. If their only leave is statutory leave (as opposed to contractual leave), it would be unlawful for the employer to allow Charlie less leave than Alice.
In the gov.uk calculator try each different option for "Is the holiday entitlement based on:"


days worked per week
hours worked per week
annualised hours
compressed hours
shifts


All else being equal you get the same results, just expressed in the units you chose there. E.g. 5.6 weeks or 5.6 shifts or 210 hours, if you work 7.5 hours per calendar day, five times per calendar week.

To be clear, my scenario has all shifts of the same length: it's just that different weeks have different numbers of shifts in them, and the employer requires (some) leave to be taken as weeks. Ambiguity arises because leave taken one week involves a different number of shifts (and working hours) compared to the next week. E.g. when Charlie, with the same shift length as Alice and Bob but on alternating weeks as I described, takes leave on a 4-shift week, should only (4 x 7.5) 30 hours be deducted from the 210, or is it acceptable to deduct (5 x 7.5) 37.5 hours (the average weekly hours)?

Think about it in terms of hours equivalent to 5.6 weeks pro rata - that's the entitlement - not "shifts" or "days".

Do you know of a source I can reference for the idea that it's the equivalent in hours that counts as the entitlement? Maybe that will clear up the crux of my question: is it only actual scheduled working hours taken as leave that can be off-set against the entitlement, or is using the average working hours for some period of leave acceptable?

"Do you know of a source I can reference for the idea that it's the equivalent in hours that counts as the entitlement?" - there isn't a source, it's just my idea to help you answer your question. The entitlement arising from WTR is some proportion of 5.6 weeks. Charlie is entitled to 28 shifts total, he uses 24, he has 4 remaining.

If you convert the 5.6 weeks into working hours then the issue OP described disappears and that looks like the sensible thing to do. But do you have any source that this is actually done that way? I'm sure there must have been cases where things like that where discussed.

@Lag Yet hours is the crux of the question, not shifts vs days.  Whats to stop an employer claiming you get 5 'weeks' and 3 'days', and if you want to book a week off in a week you work 4 days, thats 1 of your 5.6 weeks. As opposed to 0.8 if you count by hours or days.

@quarague If in the gov.uk calculator you choose "hours" as the basis for your leave entitlement then its results are in hours. E.g. "The statutory entitlement is 210 hours holiday."

@user1937198 "Whats to stop an employer [giving you less than your statutory entitlement]?"

@Lag 'You took 5 weeks off, that they are short weeks is your problem' What is there to say that's isn't the statutory 5 weeks.

@user1937198 The fact that the employer called the weeks taken "short" weeks.

@user1937198 The fact taht the employee isn't getting 210 hours of paid leave, but is given less than they are entitled.. Though to be fair it also enables an employee to take over the limit tooo. Though I think the employer would probably deny anyone's attempt to take leave on 4 long shift blocks

"It would be unlawful to make Charlie's leave entitlement less than Alice's leave entitlement. They work the same hours, they are entitled to the same leave." - could you clarify this? I don't think there's any law preventing Alice negotiating a contract with more leave than Charlie, provided they both get at least statutory minimum. Or if by "leave entitlement" you mean "statutory minimum leave entitlement" then I think we're all in agreement that A & C have equivalent entitlements, and I don't follow what it is that you're suggesting would be unlawful.

@JustATrick You're right, that was careless of me. Edited.
